# Change HP Fortify C rule priority

Tags: c, fortify

I was wondering if anyone had any information on how to change a priority on a rule in HP Fortify?

For example in C, the category "Uninitialized Variables" has the fortify priority order of LOW. I need to change to HIGH for auditing purposes. Is there any way to change a rule or do I need to create a new rule?

If I need to create a new rule, how would I make a rule that matches "Uninitialized Variables" and make it global for other users to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really way for you to modify the existing rule pack. But that's okay. There's something much easier that I can suggest that does not involve trying to create or modify custom rules (which can get a very messy if you're not careful).

The easiest thing you can do is create a custom Folder Filter.

- Open up your *FPR* in *Audit Workbench*. Select the correct *Filter Set* that you normally use.
- Your chosen *Filter Set* will be home to
  our new *Visibility Filter*. For example purposes I will use the *Security Auditor View*. Then select the *Filters* tab and click *Create New Filter*. 
  [image]
- Use the values shown below, but feel free to adjust if needed, and then click *Save*:
  [image]
  At this point, you should be able to see the *Uninitialized Variable* findings in the *High* tab.

***SPECIAL CONSIDERATIONS:***

- This change to the organization of your Fortify Findings right now, only is in effect for this one FPR. If you wish to have this filter rule exist in scan for other projects, then you will need to modify the default fortify filters be creating something called a custom Fortify Issue Template. Check your fortify documentation to get more information on this.
- If you try to upload this to SSC (Software Security Center) where you might want to perform some reporting, then the default Issue Template that lives on SSC will be used to sort and organize your scan's issues, when generating reports. If you wish for your new custom Fortify Issue Template to be used for reporting and organization withing the web UI, then you will need to override the default Issue Template on the SSC server with your new custom Issue Template. Again, see your documentation for more information on this.
- Finally, there is a way to potentially create a custom Fortify Control Flow rule (which will need to be used, together in combination, with a suppression rule) that will make it possible to essentially reassign the priority metadata for your particular issue, but this is quite difficult.

Comment: This was a great alternative! Thank you